# Cygwin commands from CMD are slow; from bash are fast

Tags: windows, cygwin

I have been using Cygwin commands from my Windows CMD prompt for several months without problems.  Within the past few days, every time I call a Cygwin command (`ls` for example), the command takes several seconds to "load" before it actually runs.  If I try the same command from within a bash prompt, it runs ("loads") immediately.

The [Cygwin FAQ](https://www.cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.slow) mentions that network drives in PATH may cause problems, so I've tried some permutations of my `PATH` variable and network connectivity.  Below, "full `PATH`" means my original path setting; "short `PATH`" means the path with only the Cygwin bin directory.  Times are reported through the `time` command.

## Timing results for `ls`

Connected to network:

- Run `ls` within `bash`: 0.124 s
- Run `ls` within CMD (full `PATH`): 41.29 s
- Run `ls` within CMD (short `PATH`): 38.56 s

Disconnected from network:

- Run `ls` within `bash`: 0.125 s
- Run `ls` within CMD (full `PATH`): 0.17 s
- Run `ls` within CMD (short `PATH`): 0.19 s

## Results for `cygcheck`

I ran `cygcheck -s` and noticed:

```
Warning: There are multiple cygwin1.dlls on your path
```

although this may be due to running `cygcheck` from within Cygwin's `bin` directory.  I completely uninstalled and reinstalled Cygwin and still see the same issue.

## Results from `netstat`

I ran `netstat -a -n` before executing Cygwin's `ls` and after execution (while it is stalled).  I did this several times and found one line from each run that appeared consistently during the delay:

```
  UDP    127.0.0.1:55030        *:*
```

The port number changed from test to test.

## `strace` results

I ran Cygwin's `strace` on the `ls` command.  Most of the delay is spent in calls such as:

```
11685  886560 [main] ls 10020 pwdgrp::fetch_account_from_windows: line: <xxxx>
```

and

```
12684  899244 [main] ls 10020 cyg_ldap::fetch_ad_account: No entry for (objectSid=\00\00\00\00) in xxxx DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx,DC=xxxx
```

Comment: This is a work computer; I cannot disable antivirus (even to test).

Comment: I have verified that all directories in my unaltered PATH exist and are local.

Comment: So now disconnecting from the network makes everything *faster*?  That isn't consistent with the results you originally posted.  Consider using Process Monitor (available from the MS web site) to examine what the process is doing during the long delay.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, yes, I must have been doing something wrong the first time.  It is also only when I am connected to my company's network (so from home, when connected via VPN).  Perhaps it is antivirus related.  I'll try Process Monitor.

Comment: Most corporate networks that provide a VPN tunnel disallow [split tunneling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_tunneling) (i.e., default route gets changed corporate VPN endpoint when tunnel is connected).

Comment: As well as Process Monitor, run `netstat -a -n` during the delay period and look for connections in a SYN_SENT state.  I've seen symptoms broadly similar to these when software is attempting to validate an SSL certificate but network access is blocked by an external firewall.  (Typically if you have no network connection at all, the attempt fails immediately, so that would be consistent.)  Doesn't have to be SSL, any other network access would have a similar effect, e.g., if Cygwin is trying to self-update or something.

Comment: Some interesting dicsussions: https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.startup-slow and https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2015-02/msg00195.html

Comment: Does the issue apply to Windows 7 only, or to Window 10 as well?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A [section](https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.startup-slow) in Cygwin's FAQ addresses slow startup times.  Cygwin recently changed to using Active Directory lookups for authentication, rather than using flat files.  Changing the defaults in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` from

```
passwd:   files db
group:    files db
```

to

```
passwd:   files
group:    files
```

skips the AD lookup.  My Cygwin commands are now speedy again.

Comment: Odd; I wonder why it needs to look anything up in the first place?  The `ls` command doesn't show the group and owner by default, IIRC.

Comment: You are a life saver! I'd upvote twice if I could :-)

Comment: I get the following error after modifying nsswitch.conf: Error: Could not fork child process: There are no available terminals (-1).

Comment: Instead of making the change suggested in this answer, I instead went to the linked section in cygwin and followed the instructions (used option 2). It is now faster. :)